# Names Not Listed in Dropdown Despite a Count of 2 in SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to figure out why everything compiles, the page loads, but there's nothing in the **Managers** drop down menu. The **Engineers** `dropdown` populates properly, but not the **Managers**. I thought that perhaps the query returned no results, but as it should, it returned **2**, I displayed the count and verified **2** matches in the table. Why would this not work?

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //var user = 
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.statuses, "StatusId", "StatusName");
        ViewBag.SystemDetailId = new SelectList(db.systems, "SystemDetailId", "SystemName");


        var engineers = db.engineers;
        var managers = db.managers;
        var mte = db.ManagersToEngineers;
        List<Manager> matchedManager = null;
        Engineer matchedEngineer = null;

        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userEmail = this.User.Identity.Name;
            matchedEngineer = engineers.Where(x => x.email == userEmail).FirstOrDefault();
            if (matchedEngineer != null)
            {
                matchedManager = mte.Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId).Select(x => x.manager).ToList();
            }

        }

        if (matchedEngineer != null)
        {
            ViewBag.EngineerId = new SelectList(new List<Engineer> { matchedEngineer }, "PersonId", "FullName");
            ViewBag.ManagerId = new SelectList(matchedManager, "PersonId", "FullName");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.EngineerId = new SelectList(engineers, "PersonId", "FullName");
            ViewBag.ManagerId = new SelectList(managers, "PersonId", "FullName");
        } 

        return View();
    }
```

Here's the cshtml for create (UPDATE: Engineer drop down shared for reference):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EngineerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EngineerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.engineer.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ManagerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.manager.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're returning `View()` but inside your .cshtml view I can see `LabelFor(model => model.ManagerId)`. So do you have strongly-typed view? Are you sure you are returning your view model object?

Comment: That's right, the label for that is just Manager, in the display annotation. That's not the issue. The managers should still show up on the list with the "FullName" attribute. The proper view model object is being used.

Comment: Can you share the razor/markup for the Engineer dropdown?

Comment: you are adding `null` in `DropDownList` for `SelectListItems` instead of binding it to `ViewBag.ManagerId`

Comment: Shared the engineer dropdown.

Comment: mmushtaq I'm doing the same for engineer yet it populates. You have to have that overload in there or something in there. The list comes from the viewbag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to instantiate a new List of Manager in the first line of **ViewBag.ManagerId**?

```
if (matchedEngineer != null)
    {
        ViewBag.EngineerId = new SelectList(new List<Engineer> { matchedEngineer }, "PersonId", "FullName");
        // new up list below
        ViewBag.ManagerId = new SelectList(new List<Manager>, "PersonId", "FullName");
    }
```

Comment: No... that was already instantiated earlier. That's what matchedManager is.

Comment: Sorry I missed that...What about your **SelecList** instantiation, you have **PersonId** instead of **ManagerId** - ViewBag.ManagerId = new SelectList(matchedManager, **"PersonId"**, "FullName");

Comment: the Manager model inherits from Person model. ManagerId is just the name of the ViewBag, it can be anything really. PersonId is right. It would get an error if I put ManagerId.

Comment: I know I'm reaching...trying to eliminate the easy stuff

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the proper ForeignKey annotations in the change model it was being displayed from.

```
public class ManagerToEngineer
{
    [Key]
    public int ManagerToEngineerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("engineer")]
    public int EngineerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("manager")]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Engineer engineer { get; set; }
    public virtual Manager manager { get; set; }

}
```